# How to update reference .dll?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have build dll for window phone developers. For example, mylibary.dll (version 1.0) and the developer add `mylibary.dll` to their app (e.g.: abc app) and publishes the app. If in the future I update my library, for example to version 1.1, I want to automatically update mylibary.dll from version 1.0 to 1.1 in abc app. How to do this?

Comment: You cannot and should not do this.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot automatically update the dll in the app. You need to follow normal procedure as any other software process. Once you are ready with the dll, you send the updated dll to the developer (via the means you both have established). The developer would then update his project by referencing your new version of dll, do the required testing and update the app in the store.